# Explicit solution to a Rayleigh quotient equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, systems-of-equations

**For 5 months!** I have been struggling to solve the following equations analytically without numeric method (i,e, Newton method):

> **Main equation:**
>
> $$
>  \biggl(M^2-\cfrac{\mathbf{x^{\text{T}}}M^2\mathbf{x}}{\mathbf{x^{\text{T}}}\mathbf{x}}E\biggr)\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{1}
> $$
>
> **Constraint equations:**
>
> $$
> \begin{cases}
>  \mathbf{x^{\text{T}}1}=0 \\
> \\
> \mathbf{x^{\text{T}}x}=u 
> \end{cases} $$
>
> where $\{M,E\}\in\mathbf{R}^{n \times n}$ and $\{\mathbf{1},\mathbf{x}\}\in\mathbf{R}^n$ are defined, then $M$ is an arbitrary symmetric matrix, $E$
>   is an identical matrix,
>   $\mathbf{1}$ is all one vector, $\mathbf{x}$ is a
>   variable vector and $u\in\mathbf{R}$ is a scalar.
>   Furthermore, as a knowledge, the below equation form is called [Rayleigh
>   quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient) $R(M^2,\mathbf{x})$:
>
> $$R(M^2,\mathbf{x}):=\cfrac{\mathbf{x^{\text{T}}}M^2\mathbf{x}}{\mathbf{x^{\text{T}}}\mathbf{x}}$$

Now, we attempt to estimate the $\mathbf{x}$. Does the analytic solution or method exist? My ability is shortage but, I guess that this problem has a beautiful solution. Also, main equation is a simultaneous cubic equation. Theoretically, this is solvable. Just, this is my theme question.

Furthermore, same question is already asked on [math overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/238431/explicit-solution-to-a-rayleigh-quotient-equation). Then answerers provided worthful information which may be solution to clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were already told the answer on MO.  Let $M^2$ have eigenvalues $\lambda_j$ with normalized eigenvectors $v_j$, and $v_j^T 1 = d_j$.
Let $x = \sum_j c_j v_j$, where you want 
$$ \eqalign{x^T x = \sum_j c_j^2 &= 1 \cr
            x^T 1 = \sum_j c_j d_j &= 0\cr}$$
and $r = x^T M^2 x = \sum_j c_j^2 \lambda_j $.
Then you want
$ (M^2 - r E) x = 1$, which says 
      $$ c_j (\lambda_j - r) = d_j$$
Thus (ignoring the possibility that some $\lambda_j = r$)
$$c_j = \dfrac{d_j}{\lambda_j - r}$$
which means you need

$$\eqalign{\sum_j \dfrac{d_j^2}{(\lambda_j - r)^2} &= 1\cr
\sum_j \dfrac{d_j^2}{\lambda_j - r} &= 0 \cr}$$
Note that the  equation for $r$:
$$\sum_j \dfrac{\lambda_j d_j^2}{(\lambda_j - r)^2} = r
 $$
follows from those two.

Since there are two (apparently independent) 
algebraic equations for the single variable $r$, there will usually be no solution. When there is, it will be the root of a complicated polynomial
which in general has no expression in radicals.